# Send email to create and attach PDF in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

The output email gets sent but does not arrive i my email. I have added dompdf library. When I removed the code that creates the pdf then the mail was sent.

My code:

```
<?php
$this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
$this->dompdf->load_html($body);
$this->dompdf->render();
$output = $this->dompdf->output(APPPATH . 'Brochure.pdf', 'F');
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$subject = "some text";
$message = $body;
$this->sendEmail($email, $subject, $message);
$config = Array(
    'mailtype' => 'html'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('ul@ul.com');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->attach(APPPATH . 'Brochure.pdf');

if ($this->email->send())
    {
    echo 'Email send.';
    }
  else
    {
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

Comment: What's output of `show_error($this->email->print_debugger());`?

Comment: if error then its give error.

Comment: I know what is that, i mean what's error shown?

Comment: doesn't give error. the output is email send

Answer (score 1):

You must be save attachment as a file, so use `file_put_contents` to save pdf to a file. Set permission to **777** to accessible by public:

```
$this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
$this->dompdf->load_html($body);
$this->dompdf->render();       
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents(APPPATH.'Brochure.pdf', $output);
chmod(APPPATH.'Brochure.pdf', 777);

$email=$this->input->post('email');
$subject="some text";
$message=$body;
$this->sendEmail($email,$subject,$message);
$config = Array(
  'mailtype' => 'html'   );


$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('ul@ul.com');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->attach(APPPATH.'Brochure.pdf');
if($this->email->send())
{
  echo 'Email send.';
}
else
{
 show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Comment: i do save the file and the attachment is save bt email doen't sent. the problem is both save pdf and send mail doesn't work.. individually its work perfectly..

Comment: I update my answer and add 777 permission to file. Please try it! @shrddhapatel

Answer (score 0):

Use this library to convert html to pdf which I have modified for CI3.
https://github.com/shyamshingadiya/HTML2PDF-CI3

Please check below mentioned solution

```
//Load the library
$this->load->library('html2pdf');

//Set folder to save PDF to
$this->html2pdf->folder('./uploads/pdfs/');

//Set the filename to save/download as
$this->html2pdf->filename('new.pdf');

//Set the paper defaults
$this->html2pdf->paper('a4', 'portrait');
```

for Sending this particular file in email.

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email PDF Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email a freshly created PDF');   

$this->email->attach($path_to_pdf_file);

$this->email->send();
```

Let me know if it not work.

Comment: its give error like         Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in /home/designsus/public_html/CodeIgniter/application/libraries/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php on line 442

Comment: You need to enable mb_srting in your php

Comment: You can find it here.  http://www.knowledgebase-script.com/kb/article/how-to-enable-mbstring-in-php-46.html

Comment: @shrddhapatel: Glad to help you out from this hurdle.